# Recommended file extension for Linux 'lftp' scripts?

Tags: linux, lftp

`lftp` allows to execute commands from the script file by using `-f` option (as described on [man page](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html)), e.g.

`lftp -f my-lftp-script-file`

Is there any file extension that is recommended (or just widely used by convention, maybe even recognized by `vim` or other editors) for such `lftp` script files?

Answer (score 0):

A script file depends from your language script you using. You are creating a script file for linux in lftp, you have to use file bash (.sh).
You can create a file with nano (or what you editor you want use) like `nano namefile.sh` and write inside it.
Later you can open it with `lftp -f namefile.sh`.